# How can i hourly resample a dataframe that has a column of tweets in it? (I would like to concatenate all tweets per hour)

Tags: python, pandas, tweepy

i have a Dataframe that has date time as index and tweets in a different column as well as other stats like number of likes. I would like to resample the df with an hourly interval so that i would get all tweets and the sum of all stats per hour, which i have done with the following code:

```
df.resample('60min').sum()
```

The problem is that my tweets column disappears.. And i need it for a sentiment analysis.
I'm new to programming so thanks in advance for reading this!

Comment: `df.asfreq('H')`? Actually, it sounds like you want to groupby each hour: `df.groupby(df.index.floor('H')).agg(...)`

Comment: But the problem is, i dont know how to code it so that it can concatenate all tweets per hour while also returning the sum for other columns like number_of_retweets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you will `groupby` and use `agg`

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
# sample data
np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.transpose([np.random.randint(1,10, 1489), ['abc']*1489]),
                  index=pd.date_range('2020-01-01', '2020-02-01', freq='30T'),
                  columns=['num', 'tweet'])

# groupby the index floored to hour, sum the num col 
# and join the tweets with a semi-colon or what ever you want
df.groupby(df.index.floor('H')).agg({'num': sum, 'tweet': '; '.join})

                    num     tweet
2020-01-01 00:00:00  69  abc; abc
2020-01-01 01:00:00  61  abc; abc
2020-01-01 02:00:00  12  abc; abc
2020-01-01 03:00:00  87  abc; abc
2020-01-01 04:00:00  35  abc; abc
```

Or if you just want to join the strings as is then sum everything:

```
df.groupby(df.index.floor('H')).agg(sum)

                    num   tweet
2020-01-01 00:00:00  69  abcabc
2020-01-01 01:00:00  61  abcabc
2020-01-01 02:00:00  12  abcabc
2020-01-01 03:00:00  87  abcabc
2020-01-01 04:00:00  35  abcabc
```